# GCE (Google Compute Engine) GPU Quota >= 1 but starting VM fails

Tags: gpu, google-compute-engine, quota

I was working with a GPU in my GCE Project and decided to request a quota increase to 2.
My VM instance-1 is in us-east1-c, so I navigated to IAM & Admin > Quotas and selected the following:
Services - selected only Compute Engine API
Metric - selected NVIDIA P100 GPUs & selected NVIDIA p100 Virtual Work Station GPUs
Locations - selected only us-east1
After receiving notification that my increased quota to 2 GPUs had been approved, I went to start my VM instance and got the error code:

[image]

I double checked my quotas page and confirmed the increase to 2 GPUs.
Support@google told me to request an incrase for GPUs Globaly, so I submitted a new request, selecting all, including the Global option:

[image]

Now when I attempt to start VM instance-1, I get:

[image]

So the error message says my quota is 0.0, however, looking at my Quotas under IAM & admin page, I have a quota of 2 in every location, including us-east1 (except for europe-west3, for some reason):

[image]

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I've tried to start new VM instances with GPUs in different locations in the same project, and also in a new project but got similar error messages each time. I've verified the locations I've chosen have GPUs using this link
To add to the confusion, no one played with any settings in the new Project I started as a testing ground; the quotas were all at the default of 1, and I still got error messages.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to request a quota increase in the region you also need to request a Global quota increase.

Similar to virtual CPU quota, GPU quota refers to the total number of virtual GPUs in all VM instances in a region. Check the quotas page to ensure that you have enough GPUs available in your project, and to request a quota increase. **In addition, new accounts and projects have a global GPU quota that applies to all regions.**

When you request a GPU quota, **you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones.**

This process is documented [HERE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus)

[image]
You can use the filter  Location = Global to find it

Now for the second error that the zone does not have enough resources, if you see 'ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED' error meaning you are encountered with the temporary resource stock-out issue at that particular zone., you should try to deploy in a different zone

I advise you to remove your second image from this thread as your project ID is visible

Comment: Thanks @Ernesto U; If I am understanding the documentation correctly, then I must enter a TTL number of Global GPUs which must be equal to the sum of the count of my GPUs in each Location however, I do not see a place to enter a Global count.  But if that is the case, then why wouldnt google set the global variable automatically?

Comment: Google does set a global variable automatically for CPUs only but not for GPUs, I can only assume it does this to protect their clients from accidentally deploying more GPUs that they intended which can cause high invoices :/ 
Sorry for a previous mistake, the correct quota is "Compute Engine API , GPUs (all regions) , location = global

Comment: so is SOP to type inside the 'Request Description' an additional request to make sure the global count is equal to the sum of all regions?  It just doesnt make sense that they would not do that automatically.  So in effect, they are knowingly causing me problems?

Comment: If you need clarification from Google on why their systems work this way I suggest you to open a Public Issue (you don't need to pay for support) in the category "Compute Engine Issue" https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers
From my end I can only make assumptions due to my experience working with many cloud providers

Comment: Thank you @Ernesto U, I've managed to get more helpful detail after several email exchanges with the google cloud support team that has been approving the quotas.  I plan on providing more detail here as soon as I can organize it all.  Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I found the form field for GPUs (all regions) and posted it as an answer here.  It does exist but the ctrl&f did not work for me so took longer to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Your *GPUs (all regions)* count must equal the sum of GPUs in each region you have requested an increased quota.  A search using ctrl & f did not work for me -- navigate to IAM & admin > click the *Metric* drop down > in the provided search bar, type  "*GPUs (all regions)* "